# App engine Channel API on symbian and other mobile OSes?

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

Does channel api work on symbian? What browser? Is there any way to make it work?
And also, for curiosity, if it doesn't work, why? What element or technology does it use that stops it from working on old mobiles (not talking about Android and iOS)?

Answer (score 1):

Channels uses long pull (comet) which suppose to be support by a a lot of browsers. I don't know what the status with Symbian, since its very fragmented, but on "normal" devices it should work.

Answer (score 1):

We don't test the Channel API against Symbian, so there are no guarantees it will work.

If it doesn't, it's more likely because of some weirdness with how Symbian handles cross-frame communication than lack of support for long-polling but there are many pieces in the chain that could break. If it doesn't work, it's very unlikely that there's any way to hack it to work.